# How can I keep an element in the same place regardless of browser size (not static though) within flow of page

Tags: css, browser, resize, tabular

I am taking care of a website where the company logo is part of a huge background image which includes about 1/5th of the page design. My boss has asked me to place an image of the logo over that background image so that it can be copied or saved as a separate file. He also wanted users to be able to link back to the homepage by clicking the logo.

I have managed to position an anchor tag over the background image, which I can then put the logo image inside of when the problem is resolved. The problem is that the positioning of the element changes when the browser is resized. How do I keep this element in the same place (over the logo section of the background image) regardless of browser size?

I took over the typo3 site and found that the design was in some sort of DW tables layout. I need to add this without totally restructuring into a DIV layout.

The site is here http://overbeckanalytics.com/typo3/menu-top/about-us.html and if you need any more code info please ask!

Comment: Thats a very very poor way of doing it... I would suggest (if you have to keep the current way of coding) or getting rid of the intricate table thing going on there, and replacing for image maps. Have a look here for more information. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the `a` within the table structure. Using firebug, the below code generally worked for me (a bit of tweaking would be in order to smooth it out). It adds a `div` inside your table row that holds the "Home" and "Contact" links. That `div` has a position relative set so that the `a` tag can then be positioned absolutely to the bottom of it, in order to keep it aligned with your logo area. Again, some pixel positioning might need to be tweaked to get it located just right, but the general idea is that you need the `a` tag positioned within that `tr` to get your effect to move with resizing.

```
<tr height="104">
  <td height="104" width="25" background="fileadmin/images/line_li.jpg"></td>
  <td height="162" width="826" valign="top" background="fileadmin/images/header_about_us2.gif" rowspan="2">
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 162px; position: relative; margin-bottom: -162px; z-index: 1;"><a style="background:none; position:absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 125px; width:300px;" href="http://overbeckanalytics.com"> <!-- <a href="http://overbeckanalytics.com" style="background:none; top: 112px; left: 228px;"> <!-- <img src="fileadmin/images/OAL_LOGO.png" border="none"> --> </a></div>
    <table height="104" width="826" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    ...more of you nested table code here...
    </table>
  </td>
  <td height="104" width="25" background="fileadmin/images/header_re.gif"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly after adjusting the position a few px like you suggested. Thank you SO much!

Comment: Your welcome. Accepting my answer would be appreciated (I note that you are new to stack overflow).